# php mysql search data with partial match on joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-like

I am trying to search data in mysql. so far using LIKE allows me to search group names if I know the exact name I am looking for. 
I need to be able to search using part of the group name and have it show all rows that have some of the search string in it. below is the code I have so far.

```
$group = $_GET['query_term'];



if (!$link = mysql_connect('', '', '')) {

    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('dbname', $link)) {

    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT os_groups_groups.*, useraccounts.* FROM os_groups_groups JOIN useraccounts WHERE os_groups_groups.FounderID = useraccounts.PrincipalID And os_groups_groups.Name LIKE '".$group."'";
```

Comment: Changing to your example gives apache error PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '%' in /var/www/mwi/public/apps/search.php on line 314

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `$sql` to:

```
$sql = "SELECT os_groups_groups.*, useraccounts.* FROM os_groups_groups JOIN useraccounts WHERE os_groups_groups.FounderID = useraccounts.PrincipalID And os_groups_groups.Name LIKE '%".$group."%'";
```

With `LIKE` you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:

- `%`   Matches any number of characters, even zero characters
- `_`   Matches exactly one character

You can read more about wildcards in:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Using the above cause the query to fail but i do not know why as i forgot how to get it to print the error

Comment: @KristopherTherrien execute the query with phpmyadmin and paste the error

Comment: ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 182